# Serializing Alternative views For MSMQ

Tags: c#, msmq

My concept is downloading a image from url and sending the image(Linked Resource)to mail message to  MSMQ!, I can sucessfully download the image , but i cannot able to send it to MSMQ, i need to serialize the Alternative Views, which i could not able to do?

Here is the code

```
MailMessage m = new MailMessage();
string strBody="<h1>This is sample</h1><image src=\"cid:image1\">";
m.Body = strBody;
AlternateView av1 = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(strBody, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);
```

Here I am Downloading the Image from url

```
Stream DownloadStream = ReturnImage();
LinkedResource lr = new LinkedResource(DownloadStream, MediaTypeNames.Image.Gif);
lr.ContentId = "image1";
av1.LinkedResources.Add(lr);
m.AlternateViews.Add(av);

 private Stream ReturnImage()
    {

        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlForImage);

            webRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
            webRequest.KeepAlive = false;

            webRequest.Timeout = 1000000000;
            webRequest.ReadWriteTimeout = 1000000000;

            using (HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse())

            {
               Stream k = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                int count = 0;
                do
                {
                    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                    count = k.Read(buf, 0, 1024);
                    ms.Write(buf, 0, count);
                } while (k.CanRead && count > 0);
                return ms;
            }
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            return null;
        }
```

Can you guys give solution for serializing the Alternative views so that i can able to send and Receive MSMQ !

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that you should take this approach.

MSMQ is designed to be ligtwheight, so sending huge data like images was not the intention - although this is technically possible, of course.

Also bear in mind that MSQM has a limit of 4 MB per message. Depending on the size of your images this might become problematic (or might not).

Instead I suggest that you save the images to a place that can be accessed by all participating application/ services/ etc., e.g. a network share, file server, or web server, or ...

Then you send only the URIs in your MSMQ message. This will be very fast to process on both sender and receiver side. Also, this will be much, much lighter on the MSMQ infrastructure.

Comment: ya Your approach is also correct, i am using asmx service, i downloaded images to a folder for each message,But i cannot able to Delete the folder images after msmq has received, It says that images are in worker process

Comment: @MazherUlHaq: That has nothing to do with the MSQM. It indicates that the code that processes the images does not properly clean up and keeps handles to the images open. Make sure that you call the appropriate `Close()` (e.g. on Streams) and `Dispose()` methods where applicable. Also watch out for hidden traps: I was very surprised that `Image.FromFile()` keeps a filehandle open until the of the application.